# Use JetBrains Mono ligatures in a document (LuaLaTeX)

Tags: fonts, luatex, memoir, fontspec, ligatures

I would like to use *JetBrains Mono* font in my document, in order to write some code. I’m using TeX Live 2020 on Windows 10, and I’m using `lualatex` and `memoir` class.

Is it possible to use *JetBrains Mono*’s **ligatures**? Thank you!

Comment: FYI: https://www.jetbrains.com/lp/mono/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This font defines its ligatures in the `calt` feature, so `\setmonofont{JetBrains Mono}[Contextuals=Alternate]` will give you what you want. E.g,

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmonofont{JetBrains Mono}[Contextuals=Alternate]
\begin{document}
\texttt{</ \#? ]\#}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Note that TeX ligatures are not on by default for typewriter fonts. So if you want TeX’s ligature for, say, em dashes rather than the ligature defined by JetBrains, use `\setmonofont{JetBrains Mono}[Contextuals=Alternate,Ligatures=TeX]`.

Comment: :-) What strange symbols. What's their use? :-) +1

Comment: @Sebastiano Just for fun, I guess, a typographer’s practice of the virtue of eutrapelia.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation...after I have searched the word "eutrapelia" that I not know :-( εὐτραπελία=εὖ + τρέπω : Aristotele).

Comment: It works! But, I do not understand why it does not work inside `lstlisting` environment. Is there a solution?

Comment: @Marco87 From the `codeanatomy` package? I’ve never used it, but give me a day (it’s time for bed here), and I’ll try to figure it out.

Comment: @Thérèse Thank you *very* much!

Comment: @Marco87 I just played with it and don’t understand the problem. The reason must have to do, not with `fontspec`, but with the inner workings of either `codeanatomy` or `listings`, neither of which I’ve used before. I suggest you ask a new question, referring to this one and asking how to make the solution here work with the `lstlisting` environment. Include a small, compilable example of your use of the environment — an example where the expected ligatures are missing —, and someone who knows those packages well will probably be able to help you.

Comment: I will do so. Thank you very much @Thérèse!