# Use JetBrains Mono ligatures with fontspec and lstlisting environment

Tags: listings, luatex, fontspec, ligatures

I would like to use *JetBrains Mono* font in my document, in order to write some code with `lstlisting` environment. I’m using `lualatex` and `memoir` class. I’m using TeX Live 2020 on Windows 10.

Is it possible to use JetBrains Mono’s ligatures inside a `lstlisting` environment? Thank you!

This is not a duplicate of the similar question [Use JetBrains Mono ligatures in a document (LuaLaTeX)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/547454/use-jetbrains-mono-ligatures-in-a-document-lualatex).

Comment: Did more experiments, and found that options like `Color=red` and `Scale=2` are respected where `Contextuals=Alternate` is not.  Found the line `\let\do\lst@do@noligs \verbatim@nolig@list` in `listings.sty`, and that looks like the culprit.  But I don’t know what to do about it.

Comment: I will try to write to the package author. @Thérèse, thank you for your help!

Comment: Just found https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/485981, which seems very relevant to your problem.

Answer (score 5):

Thank you very much @Thérèse! I found the solution in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/485981/how-to-enable-contextual-substitutions-in-lstlisting). With the following in the preamble it works:

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmonofont{JetBrains Mono}[
    Contextuals = Alternate,
    Ligatures = TeX,
]

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
    basicstyle = \ttfamily,
    columns = flexible,
}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\verbatim@nolig@list{}
\makeatother
```

@Thérèse, actually *you* found the solution. If you write an answer I will mark it as correct answer.

Comment: You worked out the application of that solution, whereas I have no experience with listings.  So you get the credit.  +1

Comment: Thank you very much @Thérèse! Very kind of you!